# Design/implement state model template solution using html css javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Design/Implement a state model diagram template solution.
This should use html/css/js to allow the ability to dynamically highlight the current workflow state for a given customer’s product.

we have used go js , it is licensed.

we have drawn rectangle and links editable save and jsn preview.

can we use this code?

Comment: hai please can anybody help in this thanks

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, I'd suggest you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) SO is **not a free coding service**

Comment: What have you attempted so far ???

Comment: Yes Riggs, I have reuired to html template solutions for different workflow

Comment: Gojs i have downloaded from Git, can i use it directly, it may ask licenced with gojs company

Comment: We got solution like, we drawn image with some tools and highlighted with specific co-ordinates of the image with highlighted js plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We got solution like, we drawn image with some tools and highlighted with specific co-ordinates of the image with highlighted js plugin.